# How to render several div in render with a function inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I can't figure this out, I tried to use  in render but still failed, how to fix this problem?

```
render() {
        return (
          {
            <div className="ABC">
              <a>ABC</a>
            </div>
            <div className="DEF">
          }
          {*Some function create inner html content*}
          {
            </div>
          }
```

I tried to add  tag but it seems like still got the error...

Comment: you need to write the whole code in single div, as react components will return the single div element

Comment: Or is there any possibility to add the DEF div into ABC div? Like return{ <div ABC> {<div DEF> </DEF>} {function}{</ABC>}}

Comment: yes you can do that way also

Comment: I added the DEF div to my code, but it still shows this "Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>" as far as I think all tags are paired up...

Answer (score 1):

The render method can only return a single root node. You can either wrap everything in a single element (such as a `<div>`), or use [react fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

You will also see the above written in short Syntax as:

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a single closing element for JSX. This might help :

```
function bar(){
    return (
          <div>
             Some other content
          </div>
    );
function foo(){
    return (
         <React.Fragment> 
                 <div>
                     Some Content in here
                     { bar() }
                 </div
         </React.Fragment> 
    );

render(){
    return(
        { foo() }
    )
```

}

Comment: But I need those content generated by the foo function in the "Some other content" div D:

Comment: So call the foo() function inside bar() and then call bar inside render.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a single **div** tag. You can do this by

```
    function foo(){
        return (
             <div> New content here </div>
        );

    render(){
        return(
           <div className="ABC">
              <a>ABC</a>
              { foo() } 
           </div>
        )
    }
```